# Plone data migration to another instance on Windows 7

Tags: windows, plone

I want to migrate the data from one Plone instance to another. I am new to Plone.
Any URLs or steps for migration are really appreciated.

Comment: Is there only one Plone site in the instance? Is there anything in the other instance already, or are you just moving data to a new machine?

Comment: there is nothing in the other plone instance. I want to move everything related to old instance including database to new plone instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to move a complete instance, you need to copy over the same data as you would back up.

That means you'll need to copy over:

1. The `Data.fs` object storage file
2. The `blobstorage` directory
3. All your customizations and installed packages, beyond Plone.

See [the Plone FAQ](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/plone-backup-move/) and [Backing up (and restoring) a Plone instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851996/backing-up-and-restoring-a-plone-instance).

Comment: Can i just copy and paste the fs file and blobstorage directory (or) do i need to run any scripts to take the backup.

Comment: Just copy is enough (shut down the instance first).