# How to back up Plone?

Tags: plone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backing up (and restoring) a Plone instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851996/backing-up-and-restoring-a-plone-instance)

We have been backing up our Plone folder (the entire folder and not just filestorage and blogstorage or data.fs) every night.   We did not stop the Plone process before doing a rsync of the Plone folder to our backup server -- because we have not launched our site yet and nobody is accessing it at night.

When we tried to restore Plone from a backup, i.e., remove our existing Plone folder and copy the entire backup Plone folder into /usr/local/ and then run /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/plonectl start, Plone started successfully but we got various types of errors when we went to the site.    Some images became missing with error like "blob file misisng" (cannot remember the exact words).    Also, when we tried to Edit our News folder (or collection), we got this error "Macro querywidget does not exist for ".  Other errors include "ValueError: Unable to find update_version_before_edit".

According to this documentation http://plone.org/documentation/kb/backup-plone, backing up Plone can be as simple as copying the data.fs folder.  So our method should work.  Is there soemthing we are doing wrong here?    Is there a cache we are supposed to clear or a catalog to re-index before we can run a restored Plone folder?   Or are we supposed to re-install Plone and then copy back the backup filestorage and blobstorage folders (this is what we do whenever we upgragde Plone)?

Thank you very much in anticipation.
cmgui

Answer (score 1):

As the document you reference states: "If you're using BLOB storage (which became a default in Plone 4 for Images and Files), you'll have to backup also the blob-objects. They are stored by default in the var/blobstorage folder of your buildout." It's not just a matter of copying the data.fs file.

Comment: Thank you Jon Stahl.   Yes, we have been backing up the blobstorage and filestorage (data.fs) folders before we upgrade our Plone, and then copying these folders back to the upgraded Plone.   But for our daily backup, we are backing up the entire Plone folder.  When we tried to run plonectl start from the restored backup Plone folder, we got the errors mentioned.  Are you saying we have to re-install Plone and then copy back the blobstorage and filestorage folders?   Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very extensive documentation on doing backups for Plone:

http://www.plone-entwicklerhandbuch.de/plone-entwicklerhandbuch/produktivserver/backup-der-zodb

Use Google Translate if you can't read german...this is all working in production with Plone 4.X.